# JDeveloper vs IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea, jdeveloper

Recently I have started work in one company. Previously I was working only with IntelliJ. Now have to wait while I get to use IntelliJ again. So I am thinking of any IDE similar to IntelliJ. How about the JDeveloper, probably somebody is been using it already, so I would like to hear from people their opinions, who is already using it, and not the comments "how great this tool is" from it's documentation.

Comment: Why not use Eclipse? It is the greatest IDE many people ever used.

Comment: I'd say stick with one being used in the company to stay consistent. And if you are not limited in choices — why don't use continue to use IntelliJ IDEA? And don't forget that there is Emacs :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux And probably the only one...

Comment: They're both IDEs.  They have their pluses and minuses.  Our company uses IntelliJ, which I do feel is good, but Eclipse is just as good in some places that IntelliJ is weak, and vice versa.

Comment: About the Eclipse, I dont know, I hate it. I would preferable more use netbeans then eclipse. The coolest thing about intellij is that its facets to all the frameworks is very great, for example, you just click on the mark of your spring bean, it takes you straight to config file. The autocompletion for XML, Java, everything works just great. Also I have to use maven a lot, intellij has great integration, while eclipse - awful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like inteliJs GUI is more polished espeially compared to eclipse . This is just my opinion though

The coolest thing with Jdeveloper ( reminds me of netbeans) is the lightbulb that shows up when there's issues with your code and most of the time you can click on it and there are fixes to a lot of your problems . In inteliJ this feature seemed less concrete imop .

They both seem similiar to me speed wise.

I also like how Jdeveloper automatically runs the class un working on rather then having to select one .

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can program with both of it (even with Eclipse ;). It depends on you and your daily work which one to use. Check the feature list and download them (they are for free ;).